# Fill missing Variables by Information from other date columns (R)

Tags: r, variables, na, calculation, difftime

I have a Dataframe which looks similar to this:

```
set.seed(42)   
start <- Sys.Date() + sort(sample(1:10, 5))
set.seed(43)
end <-  Sys.Date() + sort(sample(1:10, 5))
end[4] <- NA
A <- c("10", "15", "NA", "4", "NA")
B  <- rpois(n = 5, lambda = 10) 
df <- data.frame(start, end, A, B)
```

I would like , when there is an NA in the column A to caclulate the hours beweet start and end. Nothing shall happen when either start or end is NA.

I tried somthing like that:

```
df[, df$A [is.na(df[, df$A])]] <- difftime(df$end, df$start, units =  "hours")
```

but this gives me the Error: undefined columns selected.

Does someone have an Idea? Thanks.

Comment: but if `end` is not defined, how can you do a difference?

Comment: Sorry. I saw the Problem, therefor I added the comment "Nothing shall happen when either start or end is NA."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an index where there are `NA` in 'A' column, subset the 'start', 'end' based on the index, get the `difftime` and assign back

```
df$A <- as.numeric(df$A)
i1 <- is.na(df$A)
df$A[i1] <-  with(df, as.numeric(difftime(start[i1], end[i1], units = "hours")))
```